# How to chain/combine Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

Ok this has been bugging me for a while, wondering if any one could show me a good way of chaining Observables between multiple services.

In the example below in the Auth class what would be a good way of creating an Observable from the `this.api.postSignIn()` so the `signInSubmit()` can subscribe to it back in the component? It is worth noting that `this.api.postSignIn()` is subscribing to an Angular2 http request.

Is this a bit of an anti pattern and is there better ways of doing this?

Basically the functionality I would like to achieve is:

- Component - responsible for collecting the sign in data and sending it to the auth service in the correct format. Then once the Auth sign in is complete navigate to the admin page.
- Service - Make api call to get token, set token via the token service and set `isSignedIn` bool then defer control back to the calling component.

  ```
  @Component({...})
  export class SignIn {
     private signIn:SignInModel = new SignInModel();

      constructor(private auth:Auth, private router:Router) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      signInSubmit() {
          this.auth.signIn(this.signIn)
              .subscribe(
                  () => {
                      this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
                  }
             )
      }

  }

  @Injectable()
  export class Auth {
      private isSignedIn:boolean = false;

      constructor(private api:Api, private tokenService:TokenService) {

      }

      public signIn(signIn:SignInModel) {

         return this.api.postSignIn(signIn)
              .subscribe(
                  response => {
                      this.tokenService.set(new TokenModel(response.token));
                      this.isSignedIn = true;
                  },
                  error => {
                      console.log(error);
                  }
              );
      }

      public signOut() {

     }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leverage the `do` and `catch` operators instead of subscribing within the `signIn` method.

Here is the refactored `signIn` method:

```
public signIn(signIn:SignInModel) {
   return this.api.postSignIn(signIn)
        .do(
            response => {
                this.tokenService.set(new TokenModel(response.token));
                this.isSignedIn = true;
            })
        .catch(
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
}
```

In your case, you can't subscribe on the returned object of this method since the `subscribe` method returns a subscription and not an observable. So you can't subscribe on it...

Comment: Thanks will have a read up on the .do() and .catch(), and find out how it is different from subscribe().

Comment: You're welcome! The difference of using operators is that they allow you to plug processing into the asynchronous data flow. By subscribing, you "simply" receive events (error and completion) on an observable. This awesome tutorial will be helpful to understand this: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754.